# Symfony2 Form with multiple collection

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to integrate two collections into one form.

this is my code:

FormType.php

```
$builder
->add('Depart', 'collection', array('type' => new DepartType(), 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true))
->add('Options', 'collection', array('type' => new OptionsType(), 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true))
;
```

View.twig

```
{{ form(form.Options) }}
{{ form(form.Depart) }}
```

But, when I post the form, only the first collection: options is sent to the control.

View.twig

```
{{ form(form.Depart) }}
{{ form(form.Options) }}
```

if I change the order as above, the collection:Depart is sent, how to resolve the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe `form_row(form.Depart)` instead of `form(form.Depart)`?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work for you:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_row(form.Depart) }}
 {{ form_row(form.Options) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```